# Add business days to the new date

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add the new date with 1 business day. For example if user select any Friday, it should display Monday's date in the second field. Below is the code:

JQUERY:

```
 $(function () {

     $('.one').datepicker({
         onSelect: function (date) {
             var date2 = $('.one').datepicker('getDate');
             date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
             $('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);
         }
     })
     $('.two').datepicker({})

 });
```

HTML:

```
<input class="one" name="first" />
<input class="two" name="second" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
$(function(){
 $('.one').datepicker({
 onSelect: function(date){
  var date2 = $('.one').datepicker('getDate');
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
     var day2=date2.getDay();
     if(day2==0){
         date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
     }
     else if(day2==6){
         date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+2);
     }
  $('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);
  }
  })
  $('.two').datepicker({})

  });
```